# Using information_schema find the right one text line

Tags: sql, postgresql, information-schema

how using information_schema find same text from all columns ?

Have this :

```
SELECT    *
FROM      information_schema.columns
WHERE     table_name like '%cb%';
```

Need to find all tables name start `CB` and some column contains the text `"OutstandingAmount"`

Comment: What do you mean by: "some column contains the text "OutstandingAmount"?

Comment: I want to find this string, through the entire database @MeyssamToluie

Comment: Then using dynamic query loop through all database and store the result in a table. Finally query from created table.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name like '%cb%' and column_name ilike '%OutstandingAmount%'` ?  Also you did say "start with cb", so I would omit the first wildcard if that's what you really meant.